# int32 to hex string not working.. Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, int, hex, data-conversion

I have a int32 containing rgba values encoded in the following way:

```
values = [255, 255, 255, 255];
this.colorInt = ( values[0] << 24 ) | ( values[1] << 16 ) | ( values[2] << 8 ) | values[3];
```

in this case all values range from `0-255`

Now when i try to convert this to a hex string like so:

```
this.colorInt.toString(16);
```

I want to get this: `#FFFFFFFF` but i get this: `-1` I have seen many stackoverflow posts about this but I cant get it to work...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: color codes have three hex digits, not 4

Comment: I know, but it should still work with 4 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the integer
-1 (base 10) = 11111111111111111111111111111111 (base 2)

If you use bitwise operators, you'll see this issue, as it deals with 32 bit integers only.

Other operators like multiplication would take care of this. As they are not bitwise operators, their calculation is not limited to 32 bit integers.
You can use the following.

```
this.colorInt = 255 + (255 * 2**8) + (255 * 2**16) + (255*2**24)
this.colorInt.toString(16) // "ffffffff"
```

Otherwise what I'd suggest as a more readable approach is

```
function hexer(a,b,c,d){
    return ([a,b,c,d].map(x=>x.toString(16)).join(''))
}
hexer([255,255,255,255]) // "ffffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

the colors are represented by 3 colors (RGB), in order to introduce the alpha variable, your case won't work.

here you have your code working

```js
const values = [255, 255, 255];
const colorInt = ( values[1] << 16 ) | ( values[2] << 8 ) | values[3];

console.log(colorInt);
console.log(colorInt.toString(16));
```

Comment: May i ask why it stops working when you add alpha to the mix?

Comment: and if you do toString(24) it also doesnt work why?